# Finding MAX(DATE) value in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, greatest-n-per-group

I am new to SQL, hence this question-

I have a `DATE` column in my table and my query is supposed to fetch the value with the most recent `DATE`. I have realized that I can achieve it through any of the following ways-

1. `SELECT TRUNC(MAX(createddatetm)) cdt
   FROM (SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(createddate, 'Month dd, yyyy hh:mi AM'), 'Month dd, yyyy hh:mi AM') as createddatetm
       FROM comments WHERE  commentid = '1234');`
2. `SELECT trunc(MAX(TO_TIMESTAMP(to_char(createddate, 'Month dd, yyyy hh:mi AM'), 'Month dd, yyyy hh:mi AM')))
   FROM   (SELECT createddate
         FROM   comments
         WHERE  commentid = '1234');`
3. `SELECT TRUNC(MAX(createddatetm)) cdt
   FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(createddate, 'Month dd, yyyy hh:mi AM') as createddatetm
       FROM comments WHERE  commentid = '1234');`
4. `SELECT trunc(MAX(to_char(createddate, 'Month dd, yyyy hh:mi AM')))
   FROM   (SELECT createddate
         FROM   comments
         WHERE  commentid = '1234');`

**HERE IS MY QUESTION-**
Is there any other simpler way using which I can achieve this? Or should I should I use any of these I've mantioned? Also, are there any differences between these queries with respect to performance? I don't think there are, but I need to confirm that once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you converting a date to a varchar to convert it back to a date/timestamp again? You can just compare/use the date value stored in the database.

Your problem can easily be solved using a window function:

```
select *
from ( 
  select c.*, 
         row_number() over (order by createddate desc) as rn
  from comments
  where commentid = 1234
) t
where rn = 1;
```

alternatively using `max()`

```
select *
from ( 
  select c.*, 
         max(createddate) over () as max_createddate
  from comments
  where commentid = 1234
) t
where max_createddate = createddate;
```

or if you need that for multiple commentid values:

```
select *
from ( 
  select c.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by commentid order by createddate desc) as rn
  from comments
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: The reason why I'm converting a date to a varchar to convert it back to a date/timestamp again is I want the comparison to be made based on the date-time as well, but not use the value to display?

Comment: The comparison will _always_ be done using the date/time value. If you want to hide the time part during display, format your `date` column using `to_char()`. But it's better to retrieve the "real" values in the query and do the formatting in your application (front end).

Answer (score 0):

Why have nested Select statements when you are just looking for one simple value?

```
select  trunc( max( createddate )) cdt
from    comments
where   commentid = '1234';
```